# display.async and smooth transitions

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I have got my custom widget that changes background when hover. It is working nice but I would like to have smooth transition between no background and hover background. It will work with `GC.setAlpha()`, but:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0;i<255;i++) {
            setBG(BGHelper(imgHover,i)); //i - alpha
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   
});
```

This code wait until `i == 255`, but it doesn't display a smooth transition. Why?

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what you mean with "_it doesn't display smooth transition_"?

Comment: I would like to see smooth transition from alpha 0 to 255 (invisible to visible), but when I hover my widget it takes 1*255 miliseconds and I can see fully visible image (no steps).

Comment: The `Runnable` is (eventually) executed by the UI thread, which you are pausing with `Thread.sleep()`. Use a `Timer` or so to periodically update the alpha instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can not work, because as long as you are in your Code SWT will not repaint or change the component.

You should do the work in a separate Thread and call `Display.asyncExec` for every change.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    final int x = i;
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setBG(BGHelper(imgHover,x)); //x - alpha
        }
    });
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```